# Pass by reference again

Tags: c, pass-by-reference

I made this code to create a word dictionary. Only one of each word can exist; if it does, then the corresponding counter is incremented. If the word is in the dictionary, the `strcmp()` method is called and pointers are exchanged.

My problem is this when my function is called it uses `strcmp()`, but every time I do this,  `*wordArr` hasn't been modified at all. So every time the code runs it is comparing to "" which is automatically < any word.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

```
void placeWord(struct wordNode *words,char *tempW)
{
   int value;

    if(uniqueWordCount==0)  //HEAD
    {
       words = createNewWord(tempW);
    }   

    else ///SEARCHING AND AMMEND
    {
      while(1)
        {   
            value = strcmp(words->word,tempW);
            if(value<0)
            {
                words =createNewWord(tempW);
                (words-1)->next= words;
                words->prev = (words-1);
                break;
            }
            else if(value==0)
            {
                (words->howmany)++;
                wordCount++;
                break;
            }
         words=words->next;
            if(words->next!=NULL)
                break;
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
.
}

int main(){
.
.
.  struct wordNode *wordArr =(struct wordNode* )malloc(size * sizeof(struct wordNode));


   placeWord(wordArr,tempW);
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: it is but this is like 1/10th of th entire thing but its half way. If it was in java i would have been done 6hrs ago.

Comment: I don't see how you declare `createNewWord()`, so I can't be convinced that it contains what it needs to.  You may want to include that function.  Did you try hitting this with a debugger and stepping through your code to see if the strings you're creating are actually being created?  Also, as a formality, questions that are homework should include the homework tag.

Comment: It's difficult to tell you what the exact error is because the code given will not compile.

Comment: Actually there's a fair bit here that's confusing.  `uniqueWordCount` came out of nowhere (that is to say, I don't know if it's initialized or not).  `createNewWord()`'s implementation is uncertain (so again, can't say if you're populating your struct correctly).  Please include the rest of your relevant code so that you can get better answers faster.

Comment: *" If it was in java i would have been done 6hrs ago."* - But then you wouldn't be learning anything.  And don't cast the result of malloc in C.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the biggest problem is your assignment to words in placeWord().  Strictly speaking, all arguments are passed by value in C.  To emulate pass by reference, you need to pass a reference to your variable in and dereference it in your function.  (That is, pass in &wordArr and change the type of your words argument to struct wordNode **.)  Then you can store the current word in a variable:

```
void placeWord(struct wordNode **words, char *tempWord) {
    struct wordNode *currWordNode = *words;

}
```

To actually change the value at the head of the list, you'd have to do this:

```
newHeadNode->next = *words;  // If there was a previous head node.
*words = newHeadNode;
```

Also note that if you're not modifying the head of your linked list, you'll have to keep track of the previous node and set prevNode->next to the wordNode you're inserting.  Simply assigning to the variable that you're using to keep track of the current element in your list won't work.